# Dynamics 2013 Chart - group columns based on values

Tags: xml, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have a chart that displays total statuses by a date, and I am trying to group certain statuses together into a single column per my supervisor's request.  I have been researching this issue for several days, but due to our custom entity setup I have come up empty handed.  Here is the XML I have been toying with, as you can see I have tried to group using filters but it has gotten me nowhere.

```
  <fetchcollection>
    <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
      <entity name="opportunity">
        <attribute name="cpc_batchload" groupby="true" alias="_CRMAutoGen_groupby_column_Num_0" dategrouping="day" />
        <attribute name="cpc_status" aggregate="countcolumn" alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_0">
          <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="cpc_status" operator="in">
              <value>923020000</value>
              <value>923020009</value>
              <value>923020001</value>
              <value>923020007</value>
              <value>923020002</value>
            </condition>
          </filter>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="cpc_status" aggregate="countcolumn" alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_17">
          <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="cpc_status" operator="in">
              <value>923020004</value>
            </condition>
          </filter>
        </attribute>
      </entity>
    </fetch>
  </fetchcollection>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just simply create additional grouped option-set field (cpc_groupedstatus) in opportunity entity and create workflow to update it on cpc_status change. So you would have two status fields similar to standard "Status" and "Status Reason" fields and you would be able to create chart on cpc_groupedstatus without fiddling with xml.

**Please mark this answer useful if this solve your problem.**